# Mejor candidato. Multiplicar número por carácter

Tags: r

Tengo un df con el orden de clasificación en unas pruebas de mejor a peor resultado.

```
prueba<-data.frame(col1=c("candidato1","candidato2","candidato3","candidato4"),
                   col2=c("candidato1","candidato4","candidato3","candidato2"),
                   col2=c("candidato3","candidato4","candidato1","candidato2"),
                   col2=c("candidato2","candidato4","candidato3","candidato1"),
                   puntos=c(4,3,2,1) )

     col1       col2     col2.1     col2.2      puntos
 candidato1 candidato1 candidato3 candidato2      4
 candidato2 candidato4 candidato4 candidato4      3
 candidato3 candidato3 candidato1 candidato3      2
 candidato4 candidato2 candidato2 candidato1      1
```

Es decir, en la prueba 1 (col1) el mejor resultado lo obtuvo el candidato1, luego el candidato2....  así con cada prueba.

Todas las pruebas valen lo mismo. Luego al que obtuvo el primer puesto le doy 4 puntos, al segundo 3 puntos etc...

Entonces el candidato1 tiene un total de 4+4+2+1=11 puntos

¿cómo saco la puntuación de cada candidato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto una manera como puedes obtener el valor deseado

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 prueba<-data.frame(col1=c("candidato1","candidato2","candidato3","candidato4"),
               col2=c("candidato1","candidato4","candidato3","candidato2"),
               col3=c("candidato3","candidato4","candidato1","candidato2"),
               col4=c("candidato2","candidato4","candidato3","candidato1"),
               puntos=c(4,3,2,1) )

 #Lo importante aquí es cambiar la forma de como se muestran los datos para facilitar  
 obtener el puntaje
 prueba %>% pivot_longer(!puntos,names_to="Candidatos") %>%
            group_by(value) %>%
            summarise(puntos=sum(puntos))  

   # A tibble: 4 x 2
  value      puntos
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 candidato1     11
2 candidato2      9
3 candidato3     10
4 candidato4     10
```

La función pivot_longer ayuda mucho para ordenar la información de una manera que sea faci.l de realizar .cuando aplicamos esta función los datos pasan de .esta estructura

```
    col1       col2       col3       col4      puntos
1 candidato1 candidato1 candidato3 candidato2      4
2 candidato2 candidato4 candidato4 candidato4      3
3 candidato3 candidato3 candidato1 candidato3      2
4 candidato4 candidato2 candidato2 candidato1      1
```

a la siguiente

```
  # A tibble: 16 x 3
 puntos Candidatos value     
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
1      4 col1       candidato1
2      4 col2       candidato1
3      4 col3       candidato3
4      4 col4       candidato2
5      3 col1       candidato2
6      3 col2       candidato4
7      3 col3       candidato4
8      3 col4       candidato4
9      2 col1       candidato3
10      2 col2       candidato3
11      2 col3       candidato1
12      2 col4       candidato3
13      1 col1       candidato4
14      1 col2       candidato2
15      1 col3       candidato2
16      1 col4       candidato1
```

Que facilita realizar la agrupación y obtener los valores deseados